# Raising an assertation error if string is not an email

Tags: python, exception

I created a *class EmailParser* and check if a supplied string is an email or not with
the help of the standard librarie's email module. If the supplied string is not an 
email I raise an exception.

- **Is this a pythonic way to deal with inappropiate input values an assertation error?**
- **How do you generally check input values and report inappropiate states and values?**

code:

```
class EmailParser(object):

    def __init__(self, message):
        assert isinstance(message, basestring)

        parsed_message = email.message_from_string(message)

        if self._is_email(parsed_message):
            self.email_obj = parsed_message  
        else:
            assert False, 'The supplied string is no email: %s' % parsed_message

    def __str__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.email_obj.__str__()

    def _is_email(self, possible_email_obj):
        is_email = False

        if isinstance(possible_email_obj, basestring):
            is_email = False

        # I struggled a lot with this part - however, I came to the conclusion
        # to ask for forgiveness than for permission, see Zen of Python and
        # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610883/how-to-know-if-an-object-has-an-attribute-in-python/610923#610923    
       try:
           if '@' in possible_email_obj['To']:
               is_email = True  

       except TypeError, e:
           is_email = False

       return is_email
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class EmailParser(object):

    def __init__(self, message):
        assert isinstance(message, basestring)
```

In python, we typically don't check types. Basically, we prefer duck typing. Let the user pass whatever they want.

```
        parsed_message = email.message_from_string(message)

        if self._is_email(parsed_message):
            self.email_obj = parsed_message  
        else:
            assert False, 'The supplied string is no email: %s' % parsed_message
```

As Janne mentioned, this is not a good use of an assertion.

```
    def __str__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.email_obj.__str__()
```

You shouldn't call `__str__` methods directly. Use the `str()` function.

```
    def _is_email(self, possible_email_obj):
        is_email = False

        if isinstance(possible_email_obj, basestring):
            is_email = False
```

This is useless, because the only possible outcome is to set is_email to False which it already is. Furthermore, you know this has to be a Message object since it was returned from `message_from_string` so why are you checking whether it's a string? You know its not.

```
        # I struggled a lot with this part - however, I came to the conclusion
        # to ask for forgiveness than for permission, see Zen of Python and
        # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610883/how-to-know-if-an-object-has-an-attribute-in-python/610923#610923    
       try:
           if '@' in possible_email_obj['To']:
               is_email = True  

       except TypeError, e:
           is_email = False
```

In what circumstances can this possibly happen?

```
       return is_email
```

Don't needlessly set boolean flags. Just return True or False directly.

Better yet, raise an exception with details on what exactly is wrong rather than returning false and raising a generic exception later.

Answer (score 4):

Assertions are meant to help find bugs in the program. See [Python Wiki: Using assertion effectively](http://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingAssertionsEffectively). Quote:

> Assertions should *not* be used to test for failure cases that can
>   occur because of bad user input or operating system/environment
>   failures, such as a file not being found. Instead, you should raise an
>   exception, or print an error message, or whatever is appropriate. One
>   important reason why assertions should only be used for self-tests of
>   the program is that assertions can be disabled at compile time.
>
> If Python is started with the -O option, then assertions will be
>   stripped out and not evaluated. So if code uses assertions heavily,
>   but is performance-critical, then there is a system for turning them
>   off in release builds. (But don't do this unless it's really
>   necessary. It's been scientifically proven that some bugs only show up
>   when a customer uses the machine and we want assertions to help there
>   too.)